# I want to do Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

Tags: c#

How can I save my form when closing, and when I will open application I want to see my `SaveFormValues`? How can I do this?

For example: I close my application when I was on form 2 and when I will open I want to see form 2 again.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You need to specify EACH property You wanna save, and prepare a logic for reading it - it's not a one line operation.

Comment: Save it in an XML file and after re-open your form you load this XML file and fill your form with values of this XML

Comment: if (oName!=nameTextBox.Text||oCompany!=companyComboBox.Text)
     {
         DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save your changes",
             "Save?",
             MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,
             MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
         if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
         {
             SaveFormValues();
         }
         else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
         {
             // Stop the closing and return to the form
             e.Cancel = true;
         }
         else
         {
             this.Close();
         }
     }

Comment: ı found this ,ı think maybe it will help but ı dont understood SaveFormValues();

Answer (score 0):

I would use some kind of persistent data storage like text, xml, sql, etc and save your last form there " on close". "on load" then read from there and open the form that is stored there.

Comment: Yes ,ı want to do in c# if it is possible.

Comment: I could not come up with the code for you, but all you need to do is specify an event that handles the form close event. inside there save whatever you will need when you open the form (form location on screen, form size, values in the form, etc. and then have another event that handles the Open event and inside there read all the info you saved about the form and render the form exactly as it was when it was closed.